# What happens when we pass an argument of class type to a function in cpp?

Tags: c++, function, class, parameter-passing

My question considers cpp.

I know we pass arguments by their types (int, double, etc) to a function and each of these datatypes occupies specific size of memory. But what happens exactly when the type is a class? (i.e. we pass an object of a class type into a function.)

Comment: Why do you think that something different happens when you pass a structure/class?

Comment: Classes occupy memory just like the basic types. If you pass a class to a function, unless it is by reference or pointer, a new instance for the parameter will be created via the copy or move constructor. If the class is big, this can be inefficient. Classes that have neither copy nor move constructor can't be passed to functions directly, only via reference/pointer.

Comment: Are you asking about copy and move semantics?

Answer (score 0):

Just as with primitive types, a copy of the class type is passed to the function.

Also as with primitive types, you can pass a *reference* to a class type which does not make a copy of the object.

Comment: How much memory do they occupy? For example int occupies 4 bytes and char occupies 1 byte. What about class type?

Comment: @Saeideh: as with built-in types `sizeof(T)` (if they actually need to be copied and end up in memory).

Answer (score 0):

What happens exactly will depend on the ABI and how the argument is passed exactly. For example, there could be copy-elision if an object is passed from a temporary. Assuming the basic set up is passing an object of class type which is named and passed by value essentially the operations which happen are:

1. Space for the object is allocated on the stack.
2. The object is copied using its copy constructor.
3. The object somehow gets registered (often implicitly) to be destroyed when execution leaves the context, either normal or with an exception.

Whether any of that actually happens depends on whether the compiler can decide if there are any observable side-effects or not. There are plenty optimization opportunities.

Conceptually that’s the same as with built-in types. Class type object may also be passed using registers if the ABI allows that and the object fits.